# Setting data filters in partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I need a little help.
So I'm trying to call a lot of partial views from the same list model, each using a different filter. Is there anyway for me to pass the Datafilter value from the views into the model?

Comment: use JQuery.Ajax for this purpose.

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate?

Comment: this is the method in the model that's acting as a DataFilter. I need to set the TableName in each partial

Comment: 'code'  public void Populate()
        {
            LanguageLabels = new List<LanguageLabelRecord>();
            if(TableName == "" || TableName == null || LanguageTypeCode == "" || LanguageTypeCode == null)
            {
                //TODO; throw actual error.
                throw new Exception("Set language and give me a table name!"); 'code'

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
  $("#Result").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ControlerFolder/Controler",
      data: {someParameter(Filter): "value"},
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
    msg is the json that you can return
      }
    });
  });
});
```

If you need more help say something.